# Is MySQL's IF() broken?

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL (5.7.35) chokes with an error *"Error Code: 3158. JSON documents may not contain NULL member names."* on a query that can be simplified to look like

```
SELECT IF(false, JSON_OBJECTAGG(NULL, 'whatever'), 0) as x;
```

So I have to screen the NULL value to make it work:

```
SELECT IF(false, JSON_OBJECTAGG(IFNULL(NULL, 0), 'whatever'), 0) as x;
```

Which feels wrong as the *expr2* in *IF(false, expr2, expr3)* is not supposed be even looked at by the engine, unless I'm missing something fundamental.

So my question is, why does MySQL's IF() evaluate/analyse expressions that are not meant to be executed?

Thanks

EDIT: to clarify, my actual code was

```
SELECT IF(cl.id IS NULL, NULL, JSON_OBJECTAGG(cl.id, cl.somethingelse))
```

Comment: It will be *looked at*, it just [won't be executed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3713090/11683).

Answer (score 0):

Of cource it is supposed to be looked at and analysed for errors. What if someone else comes by later and sets the condition to true?

If nobody ever will, then you don't need a IF condition in the first place.